# CASE statement where data in one row depends on another row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data showing in my view:

[image]

I am looking for some code where if PM_NO 4 for FEB is ANNUAL then MONTHLY, QUARTERLY and HALFYEAR are null'd out.  The same goes for if PM_NO 2 for MAY is QUARTERLY then MONTHLY is null'd out etc.  Is this possible on Oracle SQL.

Regards,

Jon Ditchfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to find the last `pm_no` for each column that has a value, and then set all earlier ones to NULL:

```
select t.pm_no,
       (case when pm_no >= jan_pmno then jan end) as jan,
       (case when pm_no >= feb_pmno then feb end) as feb,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             max(case when jan is not null then pm_no end) over () as jan_pmno,
             max(case when feb is not null then pm_no end) over () as feb_pmno,
             . . .
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for you help on this.  However the issue I have is that there may be multiple rows of PM_NO's and the only thing that is the same of the "group" of PM Numbers is something called MCH_CODE.

Comment: I have managed to sort this and I am happy with the result.  However I have another issues I didn't envisage.  The SQL command is massive and I am trying to put this into a report on an ERP System.  It only allows a certain amount of characters and I need to create parameters for users to be able to enter their own information.  I am struggling to put this into a view due to the parameters.  Does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: @ditchy_jon . . . You have a new question, so ask that in a question rather than a comment.